# Configuring IIS to read specific web.config file

Tags: iis, web-config, virtual-directory

I have an IIS server with a website and a virtual directory that is mapped to a share on another server (which also runs IIS). I do not want my primary IIS server to read the web.config files that are in the virtual directories on the other server. Is there a way of making my IIS server only read the web.config file for the site that is presented locally?

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one web.config per solution parent directory. If there is, that is the one that will be used by the application.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case, when trying to browse the virtual directories they seem to be picking up the web.config file in those remote virtual directories as the error references that web.config file. Ex. my IIS server is server1 and and I have a virtual directory mapped in IIS under the site to a share on server2. When I attempt to browse the virtual directory from within IIS, I get a specific error referencing that web.config. error 500.19 Internal server error error code 0x80070032 config file:\\?\UNC\server2\d_share\share1\web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In the **applicationHost.config** file you can add the `allowSubDirConfig="false"` attribute to the `<virtualDirectory>` element